# Arrival defined by a fixed value - AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

So Im trying to determine whether another vending machine is required in the gas station (it's an exercise not a real life problem). The only thing that Im given is the fact that each minute a customer is trying to use the vending machine and on average it takes 0.95 min for a customer to buy and pay for what he bought. Im having trouble with "arrivals defined by" field. The exercise says that I absolutely must use interarrival rate. It also says that the probability distribution is unknown and that it is most definitely not exponential. My question is the following, is there any way to define interarrival rate without using a distribution function. I tried inputing the number on it's own and the simulation doesn't work. I considered using rate even though Im not suppose to but it just didn't make sense since rate already considers the distribution to be exponential which isn't the case in my simulation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement *I absolutely must use interarrival rate* I understand that you need to use an interarrival time, but not necessarily exponential. In this case you can choose any other distribution from a list of distributions (See below).
[image]

If you want those arrivals to be uniformly distributed, use the uniform distribution.

Or if you want them to arrive exactly every 5 minutes, create a bulk of the agents, delay them for 5 minutes and let them in to the system.